# having trouble intuiting analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis

My textbook seems to suggest that the analytic functions are precisely the functions that can be written in terms of $z$ alone (no $x$ or $y$ or conjugate-$z$).

Am I inferring correctly?

Does this mean that $\sin (z+x)$ is not analytic?   [where $z=x+iy$]

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, an analytic function can be expressed locally in terms of its power series.  Here one must distinguish between two related notions: real analyticity and complex analyticity.  Thus, the function you mentioned is real analytic (of two variables), but is not complex-analytic as a function of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that $f$ "can be written in terms of $z$" alone means $\partial f/\partial \bar{z}=0$ here. It is easy to check that $\partial f/\partial \bar{z}$ is "equivalent" to the Cauchy-Riemann equation.

Note that you can obviously express a complex function in terms of $x$ and $y$, i.e. the real part and the imaginary part, respectively, and that, more importantly, you can also express it in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ since both $x$ and $y$ can be expressed in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$, and that you can calculate $\partial f/\partial z$ and $\partial f/\partial \bar{z}$.

Comment: You mean "$\partial f/\partial \bar{z}=0$ is equivalent to the CR equations".

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.